# How to best handle different documents schemas in MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, model, mongoengine

I wonder how to best handle MongoDB documents with different schemas when, for example, using MongoEngine. All following documents are in one `Books` collection and I could freely add fields to the documents if it helps to solve the problem.

Let's say we have a MongoDB model `Book` which at the beginning of the project looked like this:

```
{
 '_id': ObjectId('...'),
 'author': 'Martin Luther',
 'age': '86'
}
```

As time in the project passed, additional attributes were saved (`books_published`) and some attributes changed their schema (`author`). Newer `Book` model documents look like this:

```
{
 '_id': ObjectId('...'),
 'author': {'first_name': 'Martin', 'last_name': 'Luther'},
 'age': '86',
 'books_published': 5
}
```

How could I make a `Book` model robust enough to load data into Python objects through a model class independent of its, so to say schema version?

Answer (score 0):

(MongoEngine main contributor here) The way we deal with this problem at my company is by migrating the documents whenever we apply mongoengine Schema changes (some example can be found in the docs [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/migration.html)). That way we ensure that the schema matches what we have in the database.

If for some reason, you don't want to go that way, you can check MongoEngine's `DynamicDocument` class which allows you to have fields that are not present on the schema. Also check `DynamicField` and `meta = {"strict": False}`.